# C++ unordered_map< pair<uint, uint>, UserClass > insertion

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am attempting to use the `unordered_map` to with keys as a pair of `uint` and values of the class `Tile`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

class Tile {
public:
  std::pair<uint, uint> coordinate;

  bool operator==(const Tile &t) {
    return this->coordinate.first == t.coordinate.first
      && this->coordinate.second == t.coordinate.second;
  }

  Tile (uint x, uint y) {
    this->coordinate.first = x;
    this->coordinate.second = y;
  }

  std::pair<uint, uint> GetCoor() const 
  {return this->coordinate;}

  uint GetX() const 
  {return coordinate.first;}      

  uint GetY() const 
  {return coordinate.second;}          
};

struct TileHash {
  std::size_t operator()(const Tile &t) const
  {
    size_t seed = 0;
    boost::hash_combine (seed, t.GetX());
    boost::hash_combine (seed, t.GetY());
    return seed;
  }
};

int main ()
{
  std::unordered_map<std::pair<uint, uint>, Tile, TileHash> board;
  Tile t1 = Tile (0, 0);

  board.insert (std::make_pair (t1.GetCoor(), t1));
  //board[t1.GetCoor()] = t1; // This causes a different error at compile time...    
}
```

I get following error followed by some notes that I did not paste here

```
/usr/include/c++/v1/unordered_map:400:17: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const TileHash'
        {return static_cast<const _Hash&>(*this)(__x.__cc.first);}
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/v1/__hash_table:1712:21: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__unordered_map_hasher<std::__1::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::__1::__hash_value_type<std::__1::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>,
      Tile>, TileHash, true>::operator()' requested here
    size_t __hash = hash_function()(__x);
                    ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__hash_table:1692:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__hash_table<std::__1::__hash_value_type<std::__1::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, Tile>,
      std::__1::__unordered_map_hasher<std::__1::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::__1::__hash_value_type<std::__1::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, Tile>, TileHash, true>, std::__1::__unordered_map_equal<std::__1::pair<unsigned
      int, unsigned int>, std::__1::__hash_value_type<std::__1::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, Tile>, std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >, true>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__hash_value_type<std::__1::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, Tile> > >::__insert_unique_value' requested here
    return __insert_unique_value(__x);
```

I know that my instantiation of the `unordered_map` is ok, when I compile without a call to insert all is well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your hasher is meant to hash the key, not the value.

Comment: `std::unordered_map<std::pair<uint, uint>, Tile, TileHash>` would want to call `TileHash` passing `std::pair<uint, uint>` to it, not `Tile`. In other words, to be usable in `std::unordered_map<K, V, Hasher>`, `Hasher` needs an `operator()` that takes an instance of `K`, not an instance of `V`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Via `TileHash`, you're providing a hasher function that takes a `const Tile&`.

The implementation is looking for a hasher function that takes a `const std::pair<uint, uint>&`.

That's because it's the key that gets hashed, not the mapped-value.

So, you're hashing the wrong thing.

---

The standard doesn't give us a hasher for pairs, but Boost does:

```
std::unordered_map<
   std::pair<uint, uint>,
   Tile,
   boost::hash<std::pair<uint, uint>>
> board;
```

Comment: How can I pass ``boost::hash_value`` as the hasher to unordered_map?

Comment: @gaigepr: Sorry, I understand neither your question nor your goal. What is it that you're actually trying to accomplish? And why?

Comment: @gaigepr: And did you read the passage in the documentation for `boost::hash_value` that says _"generally shouldn't be called directly by users"_?

Comment: `std::unordered_map<std::pair<uint, uint>, Tile, boost::hash<std::pair<uint, uint>>>` should do the job?

Comment: I just found that... My goal is to have a pair of (x, y) coordinates as keys to the unordered_map.

Comment: @gaigepr: That's not a goal; that's how you think you should implement the solution to a goal.

Comment: Your solution worked. Thank you! The larger goal is to represent a hexagonal tile map in a hash table. I have done this with arrays before and now wish to do it with some form of hash table and the unordered_map seemed to be the best option without using multiple non-standard libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Your hash function hashes the type Tile. Instead, you should specify a hash function over the key of type std::pair< uint,uint >, so that the map keys could be hashed.